# Competent addition of events in javascript

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon! I want to write my own library. The main class in it is Event. It performs a lot of hard work. I want to make it so that the programmer, using this library, could add his small events like userEventFirst, userEventTwo, etc., in a specially designated place. That he did not look for this place, and was not mistaken, I want to give him an "interface".

Here is my class:

```
addEvent = function () {

    this.userEventFirst = function () {};
    this.userEventTwo = function () {};

    this.attachEvent = function (event, handler) {

        switch ( event ) {
            case 'eventFirst':  this.userEventFirst = handler;  break;
            case 'eventTwo':    this.userEventTwo = handler;    break;
        }

    };

    this.working = function () {

        this.userEventFirst();  

        //... hard work
        var div = document.getElementById('text');
        div.innerHTML += 'class working<br>';

        this.userEventTwo();
    }   

};
```

And here the programmer takes my class, and appends the actions:

```
// programmer use my class:

addEvent1 = new addEvent();

addEvent1.attachEvent('eventFirst', function() {

        var div = document.getElementById('text');
        div.innerHTML += 'user event First<br>' ; 

});

addEvent1.attachEvent('eventTwo', function() {

        var div = document.getElementById('text');
        div.innerHTML += 'user event Two<br>' ;

});

addEvent1.working();
```

Everything is working. Only how competently is it done? performance may be lost, etc. Such events can be a dozen, they can be called in a cycle or in a timer. And the programmer can ask not all events, but only what he needs. You see, I've programmed before only in pascal )

https://jsfiddle.net/gevaraweb/0u3ff2a4/8/

Comment: `Everything is working` - then there is no question that is relevant for stackoverflow - perhaps you want codereview.stackexchange.com instead